# USB interrupt detection check

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to find out USB slave detection interrupt in kernel source code. I am using IMX8MM platform as slave USB device. I want to implement parallel ISR on USB detection interrupt. When USB is connected with host, slave USB driver would have generated some software interrupt. I want to use that interrupt as indication to top user application using custom ISR on it. I can see below interrupt in `/proc/interrupt`.

`58: 0 0 0 0 GICv3 72 Level 32e40000.usb`

Please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such events should be reported through the kernel's hotplug uevent mechanism. On most Linux systems such hotplug events are processed in userspace through *udev*. As such, it should be as simple as writing a *udev* rule, initiating the desired action.

If *udev* is available on your target platform you can use (as `root`) the command

```
udevadm monitor
```

to get a live display of hotplug events in realtime. You can use that as a starting point to write an appropriate udev rule.

---

You most definitely should not attempt to mess with kernel internals and "soft" interrupts here. For one, there is no need to do so. And more importantly, messing with such details in the kernel may cause hard to debug system instabilities.

Comment: Hi @datenwolf, when I run `udevadm monitor` command.  I observe below lines.

KERNEL[16689.152346] change   /devices/platform/usbphynop1 (platform)
UDEV  [16689.155956] change   /devices/platform/usbphynop1 (platform)
KERNEL[16689.336757] add      /devices/platform/soc@0/soc@0:bus@30800000/30a30000.i2c/i2c-1/1-0050/typec/port0/port0-partner (typec)
KERNEL[16689.336938] change   /devices/platform/soc@0/soc@0:bus@30800000/30a30000.i2c/i2c-1/1-0050/power_supply/tcpm-source-psy-1-0050 (power_supply)

Why I see I2C device when I connect board with PC over USB?

Comment: @Ajita: My best guess would that the I²C devices coming online are part of the USB port's power delivery and monitoring system. Practically every IC related to USB power talks over I²C to the main CPU.

Comment: how to generate some kind of trigger when above log is received. Basically I want to implement one pop up window which ask user In what mode you want to use USB slave. ex. mass storage, keyboard or just charging. similar behavior when mobile phone connects with PC, it pops up similar options.

Comment: @Ajita: There are several way to do this, but they all make use of *udev* in one way or another. You could have a monitoring program run in the user session that uses [libudev](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/libudev.html), to talk to the udev daemon directly. Or you could implement some udev rule (inside a file placed in `/etc/udev/rules.d`) with a `RUN` clause that would send a notification to the user session to display that popup.

Comment: Hi @datenwolf, can you give me idea how to differentiate between USB host and USB charger?

Comment: @Ajita: I'd simply try to talk to the peer assuming it was a host, and if that fails, consider it to be a non-host.